# How to synchronize my Banshee's library to my Android's library?

Tags: android, sync, banshee, libraries, audio-sync

I want my Banshee's library to synchronize to my Android's library instead of my Android's library synchronizing to my Banshee's library because my Android's library changes more often than my Banshee's library.  So I need it to be the opposite way it is by default, and now.  Here is a visual example:

**How it is:**  Banshee's library **➜** Android's library

**How I want to be:**  Android's library  **➜** Banshee's library

Comment: May be "DropBox" can help you?

Comment: It is too slow.

Comment: I'm still looking for answer.

Comment: Are you still alive,  What I mean is your account isn't dead if not than I will start a bounty on this question if you havn't figure it out by now, or not need to,

Comment: I'm here. ;) It's not urgent since I'm mostly using Spotify now but I'm curious for the answer.

I cannot belive it's question from 2012. :D

Comment: Two years latter

Comment: @marines It's now five years later and `banshee` hasn't been updated in Ubuntu since version 12.04 (End of Live).  Can this question be closed as Un-reproducible now?

Comment: I guess. I don't have enough reps to do it myself though.